# I have moto g 1st gen charging very slow

Tags: battery, charging

I have Moto G 1st Gen now the problem is charging is very slow it takes about 3 2 and half hours to full charge
 what to do now? should i buy new battery..??

Comment: Just making a point, my brother has the Moto X 3rd gen and that is about how long he has to charge it as well. That may be typical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTechy

Try to put your phone on Airplane Mode While Charging.
Switch off your phone while charging.
Use 3G instead of 4G it will save battery.
Remove Unwanted apps.
Remove Battery and insert again.

If your phone under warranty than submit to service centre and complain them about [phone charing](http://www.thesoftwarehax.com/2015/08/charge-android-phone-faster-charging-tricks.html) issue, may be you can get replacement for battery.

Answer (score 0):

Battery may, or may not, not do it.  I just replaced my Moto G Gen 1 battery with a brand new one because I was having the same issue.  It did not resolve the issue.  I suspect my charging port is bad or something in the charging circuitry is bad.  Even with the phone completely off it takes about 24 hours to fully charge.  When the phone was new it would full charge in about an hour.

Trying the battery is a cheap thing to try though, I found a new battery (with tools needed to open the phone up), for $6 (shipped) from Aliexpress.  They say batteries can only be done by the factory, but it's actually pretty easy to do yourself with instructions found online.